# Split TreeMap<List<>,List<>> into two ArrayList

Tags: android, arraylist, treemap

i have two `ArrayLists`:

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>(10);
List<Drawable> drawables = new ArrayList<Drawable>(10);
```

which i want to sort alphabetically.

For this i created a `TreeMap`:

```
Map<List<String>, List<Drawable>> myMapToSort = new TreeMap<List<String>, List<Drawable>>();
myMapToSort.put(names, drawables);
```

**First two Question**

Is the map now sorted in `lexicographical` order? Or do i Need to do something additional?

After i have sorted them, if they are yet, i want to split them back again to `List<String>` and `List<Drawable>`. And i tried like this:

```
List<String> sortedNames = new ArrayList<String>(myMapToSort.keySet());
```

Of course it doesn't work because `myMapToSort.keySet()` Returns a `Set` and not `List`.
And `List` doesn't have an `Constructor` for a `Set`.

So how can i accomplish that and what i'm misunderstanding?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: There must be a very envious user who downvoted a ordinary question without providing potential improvments! ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out by my own.

The key was to create a `TreeMap` with not two list but two single Objects:

```
Map<String, Drawable> myTreeMap = new TreeMap<String, Drawable>;
```

Then add the `Items` from the `Arraylists` one by one to the Map:

```
for(int i = 0; i<names.size(); i++) {
        myTreeMap.put(names.get(i), drawables.get(i));
}
```

Now the Map is automatically sorted `Lexicographical` in relation with the Drawables.
That means `Names and Drawables are sorted in lexicographical order`.

If you want to retrieve the `keys` and the `values` and put them back in seperate `ArrayLists` simply type:

```
List <String> mySortedNames = new ArrayList<String>(myTreeMap.keySet());
List <Drawables> mySortedDrawables = new ArrayList<Drawables>(myTreeMap.values());
```

That's it. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use SortedSet (or SortedList) to have sorted elements. The elements are ordered using their natural ordering, or by a Comparator typically provided at sorted set creation time.

For splitting a Map in two lists :

```
List<String> sortedNames = new ArrayList<String>();
List<Drawable> drawables = new ArrayList<Drawable>();

for (Map.Entry<String, Drawable> entry : map.entrySet())
{
  sortedNames.add(entry.getKey()
  drawables.add(entry.getValue());
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work i get a `12-25 23:39:06.167: E/AndroidRuntime(12422): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList is not Comparable`

Comment: that was not the Problem i implemented it that way because i thought you Forget that Detail and i was the only Logical way to implement that. But i figured it out by my own and i will post the answere. but thanks for you help anyway!